# Test Cases Failing with Bad_Access when using SDK as a framework

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, frameworks, cocoapods

Test cases are failing when I am using tag in podfile instead of full git url.
Test cases are crashing with bad access if accessing any variable.
pod 'ABCFramework', '2.0.0-alpha1'  **This is failing the test cases**
pod 'ABCFramework', 'full git url'  **Working fine**
Any help will be appriciated. Thanks